# Why do my if statements not work in for loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, if-statement

So this is my second program I've tried writing an if statement in a for loop. The first one was unnecessary, but this one "needs" it. I put needs in quotes because I'm new to C++ and have not learned/thought of another method.

My program:

```
int main()
{
    int x, z;
    cout << " x | z |                  y\n"
         << "---------------------------\n";
    for (x = 1; x <=5; x++)
    {
        for (z = 2; z <= 6; z++)
        {
            double y = x*z/(x-z);
            if (x - z == 0)
            {
                cout << setw(2) << x << setw(4) << z << setw(21) << "Function Undefined\n";
            }
            else if (x - z != 0)
            {
                cout << setw(2) << x << setw(4) << z << setw(21) << y << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, I get a table with the first loop sequence (x = 1) completed, but then it crashes (Windows is looking for solution box pops up). It writes out the correct values only for x = 1 (the outer loop does not repeat to x = 2 and so on).

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the if statement just before the actual math. If you divide by zero, an error will occur. 
Put the math in the else if block.

Answer (score 4):

«whisper»...hey...you are dividing by 0 boy...